# Appengine object has no attribute '_projection'

Tags: app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I use this

```
class Ad(db.Model): #change to ndb.model 
    ndb_usr = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

But when I try this `if ad.ndb_usr:` I get the error. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you forgot to actually apply the change mentioned in the comment: `#change to ndb.model`.

So you're attempting to reference an `ndb.KeyProperty()` property (which most likely is specific to an `ndb.Model` object) inside a `db.Model` object. With the 2 classes being very similar, but not identical, it's quite possible for some of the code from one class to not immediately fail and make quite some progress (on potentially hard to predict paths) when invoked on instances from the other class.

I tried to repo with my existing code (changing just the models from `ndb.Model` to `db.Model`) and I got similar errors, but not exactly the same one (well, different code):

```
AttributeError: type object 'ApartCILabel' has no attribute 'query'
```

and

```
AttributeError: type object 'ApartCILabel' has no attribute '_get_kind'
```

The last one, for example, is easily explained - `ndb.Model` has a `_get_kind` method, `db.Model` doesn't. From [NDB Cheat Sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic):

```
class MyModel(db.Model):             class MyModel(ndb.Model):

@classmethod                         @classmethod
def kind(cls):                       def _get_kind(cls): 
    return 'Foo'                         return 'Foo'
```

**Update:**

I see the [DB to NDB Client Library Migration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb) migration guide came into existence, most likely a better reference than the above-mentioned (older) cheat sheet.

Comment: 19 hours later, I've rewritten the whole app to NDB and it's much better. Everything works.